# How to apply RecurrenceTable or Array in two dimensions

Tags: difference-equations

This question relates to 104959. How can I solve the following (akward) code by using RecurrenceTable or Array?

```
Clear[a, n, k, i, j]
a[n_, k_] := a[n, k] = a[n, k - 1]*(7 - k)/6 + a[n - 1, k]*k/6
a[n_, 0] := 0;
a[0, k_] := 0;
a[1, 1] = 1;
a[1, 2] = 5/6;
a[2, 1] = 1/6;
Grid[Table[1.*a[i, j], {j, 1, 6}, {i, 1, 10}]]
```

Comment: You mean you want to get a closed expression?

Comment: I wonder how I can use Array or RecurenceTable instead of using a[n_, k_] := a[n, k] = a[n, k - 1]*(7 - k)/6 + a[n - 1, k]*k/6  I am not good at using Array.